# Finding a file with the same modification time as another

Tags: files, find

For each photo my camera produces both a IMG_NNNN.JPG and a IMG_NNNN.CR2 file, that have exactly the same modification time (which, coming from a FAT-formatted SD card, is always an even number of seconds).

I keep JPG and CR2 separately, but I sometimes need to find the CR2 that corresponds to a given JPG. My current scripts use something like:

```
find /path/to/CR2s -name $(basename $jpgfile .JPG).CR2
```

But unfortunately due to numbering rollover using the name alone is no longer sufficient. Using the name and the modification time would be perfect, but something like:

```
find /path/to/CR2s  -name $(basename $jpgfile .JPG).CR2 -newermt  "$(stat -c '%y' $jpgfile)"
```

doesn't work because `newermt` seems to perform a strict inequality comparison (same with `newer`). In addition `newer...` options are not really bullet-proof since searching the CR2 of an old JPG could find the CR2 of a newer homonym.

So:

- Am i overlooking an option in `find` (GNU findutils 4.7.0-git)?
- Or is there an elegant way to do this (taking in account that files with the same name are normally years apart)?

Comment: "Long list"????

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you can do

```
autoload age

file=/path/to/something.JPG
ls -ld -- **/$file:t:e.CR2 (De'(age :$file :$file)')
```

To find the `something.CR2` files that are exactly the same age as `$file`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, even if I shall remain with bash for the time being. I found that my starting hypothesis was wrong anyway, timestamps look the same because they are rounded/truncated to the nearest even second, but there are a few cases where the time stamps are off by two seconds.